# C++ Dll library crashes on vector.push_back after second clear

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I am making a library for obs-studio using VS2019 - C++ and now I am facing an issue with vectors.

Part of the code is:

```
#include <obs-module.h>
#include <media-io/video-scaler.h>

#include <wchar.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <numeric>
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <stream>

struct filter {
    std::unique_ptr<Ort::Session> session;
    cv::Mat outputBGR;
    std::vector<const char*> input_names;
    std::vector<const char*> output_names;
};

static void createSession(struct filter* tf) {
    Ort::SessionOptions sessionOptions;
   
    tf->input_names.clear();
    tf->output_names.clear();
    tf->input_names.push_back(tf->session->GetInputName(0, ort_alloc));
    tf->output_names.push_back(tf->session->GetOutputName(0, ort_alloc));
}
```

`Session` is obtained from the ONNX Runtime.
The issue is that when I try to refresh the `tf` variable using createSession method, the program (OBS-studio) crashes. This occurs in the second calling (at the `push_back` instruction).

Currently, I am using

```
if (tf->input_names.empty()) {
...
}
```

to avoid a second clear and push, but I would rather avoid the `if` condition.

I tried to obtain the values from `GetInputName` into a variable and the move to `input_names` but it did not work.
There is no problem with `GetInputName` because I can call many times.

I also tested to stack several `clear` and `push_back` in the same method and crashed in the second `push_back`:

```
tf->input_names.clear();
tf->output_names.clear();
tf->input_names.push_back(tf->session->GetInputName(0, ort_alloc));
tf->output_names.push_back(tf->session->GetOutputName(0, ort_alloc));
tf->input_names.clear();
tf->output_names.clear();
tf->input_names.push_back(tf->session->GetInputName(0, ort_alloc)); // <<< crashes here.
tf->output_names.push_back(tf->session->GetOutputName(0, ort_alloc));
```

Please, let me know if there is anything I might be missing.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 v16.11.5
Visual C++ 2019 v14.29.30133
Windows SDK v10.0.22000.0

Comment: That's a lot of raw pointers you don't need. The error might be related to one of those, but we don't have a reproduction here. I'm guessing ort_alloc is doing memory allocation on the same line as the push_back?

Comment: What does `tf` point to? Could it be a dangling pointer (already freed or deleted)?